Scipy correlate function inconsistencies
I am writing python code to take the cross-correlation of two numerical arrays and graph it against the welch frequency interval. When compared to a manual cross correlation function we have (which runs much slower), the scipy.correlate function is much less accurate for lower frequencies (graph attached below). I was hoping to figure out why that might be. I am using the 'same' mode on the correlate function since the 'full' mode returns an array that's doubled in size which I cannot graph against the appropriate welch frequencies. (I apply a fftshift to the array before graphing it but that happens to both with the same code so I doubt that's where I'm going wrong.). Here's our manual correlation function:
def correlation_vectorized(V1, V2):
    assert V1.size==V2.size
    n = V1.size
    lags = list(range(0,n,1))
    V2doubled = np.concatenate((V2,V2))
    cor = np.zeros(n)
    for lag in lags:
        cor[lag] = V1.dot(V2doubled[lag:lag+n])
    cor = cor/n
    return cor

The array of correlated elements is normalized at the end before being returned. Here's the function call I make to the correlate function:
(correlate(V1,V2,mode='same',method='fft'))/(V1.size)

I normalize the output here, too. I have tested with both, 'fft' and 'direct' methods and they seem to give the same results (shown in graph)
Here's the graph of all 3:
The black represents the manual function, the red represents the 'direct' version, and the green represents the 'fft' version. Having manually cross-checked the numbers, 'direct' and 'fft' are definitely completely overlapping. What's strange is that the correlate function pretty accurate at higher frequencies but completely off at lower ones. What could be causing this?

Convolution involves reversing the filter. Try with a small array eg say a = 1:10 and b = 11:20 and use both functions and you will notice that the results from each are different. That is because what you want is not what correlate is doing
